# How to only call NotificationManager at 10% increments

Tags: android

I have a service running that uploads photos. I have a progressbar that is updated by NotificationManager, however its being called multipletimes.

`IntentService[n identical 127 lines`

How can I make it so that the manager only notifies when increments of 10% are uploaded?

```
@Override
        public void writeTo(@NonNull BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            long fileLength = mFile.length();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            long uploaded = 0;
            int read;

            while (is_uploading && (read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                int percent = 10* (int) (10 * uploaded / fileLength);
                mManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, uploadingProgressNotification(String.valueOf(current_image_uploading+1), percent + 10));
                uploaded += read;
                sink.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }



        }
```

Edit:

```
@Override
        public void writeTo(@NonNull BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            long fileLength = mFile.length();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            long uploaded = 0;
            int read;

            while (is_uploading && (read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                int percent = 10* (int) (10 * uploaded / fileLength);
                if(percent % 10 == 0){
                    Log.d(TAG, "writeTo: test");
                    mManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, uploadingProgressNotification(String.valueOf(current_image_uploading+1), percent + 10));
                }
                uploaded += read;
                sink.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }



        }
```

The `Log.d(TAG, "writeTo: test");` is still being called many times even though it should only be 10 times.

`IntentService[n identical 346 lines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
int percent = (int) (100 * uploaded / fileLength);
if(percent % 10 == 0 && lastPercent != percent){
   lastPercent = percent;
   mManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, uploadingProgressNotification(String.valueOf(current_image_uploading+1), percent));
}
```

also create globle variable `public int lastPercent = 0;`

Comment: hmmm I tried but it's still being called alot of times ```IntentService[n identical 1326 lines```